# c++ random numbers -100 to 100

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I want to generate a list that contains random numbers from -100 to 100. The code I have so far just goes from -50 to 50.

```
for(int line=0;line<100;line++) //reads individual lines and compares them
{
    ofs<<rand()%101 + (-50)<<endl;
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: I can point you to the `<random>` header. Also, `std::generate` is good at what its name implies.

Comment: -100 to 100 is a span of 201 numbers, so you need `% 201 - 100`.  The `% 201` gives you numbers between 0 and 200 inclusive, so -100 from there gives you the desired result range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you want values from -100 to +100, which is a range of 200 values, so you'd really want:

```
rand() % 200 // possible off-by-one error
```

This will give you 0..199. To get closer to the range you want, subtract 99:

```
(rand() % 200) - 99
```

This will give you the range -99..+100. This is closer to what you want.

You should be able to go back now and tweak to get the range you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Change to `%201` and `+(-100)`. A little experimentation would have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

`rand() %201 - 100` works just right